# scipy eigs finds complex eigenvectors, although they should be real

Tags: scipy, complex-numbers, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have a 1047x1047 sparse matrix and am interested in its eigenvectors and eigenvalues. From the mathematical derivation I know that these must be real. scipy eigs finds complex ones though. Unfortunately this destroys everything. There is no possibility to create a minimal example, because for small matrices eigs also calculates real eigenvectors, i.e. complex eigenvectors with imaginary part zero.

Desperate thanks!

Comment: *"From the mathematical derivation I know that these must be real."* Do you know this because the matrix is symmetric? If so, use [`scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html).  What are the magnitudes of the imaginary parts relative to the magnitude of the largest eigenvalue?  Is the imaginary part just numerical noise?

Comment: "*There is no possibility to create a minimal example, because for small matrices eigs also calculates real eigenvectors"*  That just means your minimal example requires a matrix that is not small.  At what size does the problem start to show up?

Comment: This comes from the requirements to the matrices that make up my final 1047x1047 matrix, which is not symmetric. Creating the source matrices simply takes too much code to show here. It takes a lot of time to create an example so if possible I'd like to avoid it. I guess the problem is also existent for smaller matrices and getting worse for bigger ones. But at the beginning the imaginary part ist very small.